# How to dynamically get the class variables in Java?

Tags: java

How to extract each column value from a list of object using the column name dynamically or how to convert it into a array of column values?

I am trying to replicate the following .NET (C#) code in Java.

```cs
StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(textFileName, true);
foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
{
    
  object[] array = row.ItemArray;
  for (i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
    
  {
    file.Write(array[i].ToString());   
    if (i < array.Length - 1)
       file.Write(",");                                 
  }                    
    
}
```

In the above code - 'table' is a data table, I'm iterating over the rows and storing each row in an array and writing the contents to the text file one by one.

Likewise, in java in place of the dataTable used in .net, I have used a List<?> (List of UserDetails model class)

```java
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
public class UserDetails {
    public String Id;
    public String firstName;
    public String lastName;
    public String department;
}
```

```
List<UserDetails> userList = getDate();

public List<UserDetails> getData(){
DataSource dataSource = jdbcTemplate.getDataSource();
        if (dataSource != null) {
            try (Connection con = dataSource.getConnection()) {
                CallableStatement cs = this.getCallableStatement("getUsersSp", con);

                int c = 0;
                while(isResultSet){

                    ResultSet resultSet = cs.getResultSet();
                    while (resultSet.next()) {
                    UserDeatils u = new UserDeatils();
                    u.setId(resultSet.getString("ID"));
                    u.setfirstName(resultSet.getString("FirstName"));
                    u.setlastName(resultSet.getString("LastName"));
                 u.setdeapartment(resultSet.getString("Department"));

                   userList.add(u);
}}}}

}
```

I want traverse through the list, get each userDetail and put them into a text file ',' seperated

```
FileWriter fos = new FileWriter("D:/data/file.txt");
//String Columns = ["Id","firstName","lastName","department"]
for(UserDetails value : batchList){  
      /// I want to replicate  object[] array = row.ItemArray; in java here 

/// want to avaid value.getId....
      fos.write();                      
}
```

I am looking for similar implementation to the C# code given (or) an alternative way to achieve it instead of manually using the get methods for all variables present in a class, it would be better to get them dynamically to reduce number of lines in a code. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: What is a column in this problem? What are the contents of the list? Just Objects with no methods and no fields?

Comment: It's not exactly clear what you are trying to do. what does `file` do? do you have a list and you want to save that list in a plain text? something like that? please edit your post clarifying your problem. Maybe the article [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [minimal reproducible element](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) detailing the expected behavior and the error messages that you are getting

Comment: You can utilize the _[String#join](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#join(java.lang.CharSequence,java.lang.Iterable))_ method to concatenate a list of values.  Or, do you need that specific code translated to Java?

Comment: Have updated the question, please take a look